# Windows10でユーザのログオン履歴の確認

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 で複数ユーザーのログオン履歴を確認したいと思っています。

ローカルグループポリシーエディタでアカウントログオン　イベントの監査、ログオンイベントの監査
を成功、失敗にしたところ、イベントビューア＞Windowsログ＞セキュリティ　内で 4624 Log onは記録されるようになりましたが、
ユーザー(U):欄は　N/A
一覧表示欄の　ログオンID欄は、0x3E7のような表示になっています。

ユーザー名を確認するには、どうしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logonのイベントは、ユーザーによる明示的なログオン以外にも、サービスなどバックグラウンドで動作するプログラムが資格情報を利用するためのログオンでも記録されます。そのようなログオンの場合、SYSETMという特殊なアカウントが使用されるため、ユーザー名が表示されない場合があります。そのようなSYSTEMによるログオン処理は大量に発生するため、イベントID 4624を検索しただけは、通常ユーザーのログオンが見つけにくなっているだけの可能性はあります。

手元の環境(Windows 11ですが、たぶん同じでしょう)で試したところ、ユーザーのログイン処理があるとき、4648というログオン試行のイベントが発生するようです。ログオンに成功していれば、その直後に、4624のイベントがあり、新しいログオンのセキュリティIDやアカウント名などでユーザー名(Microsoftアカウントでログインしている場合はMicrosoftアカウント名も)が書かれているはずです。4648のイベントを目印に確認してみてください。(ログオン処理は、ユーザーの資格情報でバックグラウンドの処理をすることがあるため、一回のログオンでも、ログオンイベント自体は複数発生していることがありますので、ご注意ください。)